# I can't find any documentation on this CSS selector.. what is it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using jQuery to change the width of a sidebar, and within the working code on CSS it shows this:

```
#wrapper.MenuDisplay #my-sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 200px;
}
```

But after looking through w3schools and mozilla etc, I have not found any selector which looks like #foo.bar.

The reason I am trying to figure this out is that I can't understand why this CSS isn't applied straight away, and how a jQuery toggleClass is able to get this width to be applied (which it successfully does) on a button click.

Does anyone know what is going on here? What the selector is and why it works after clicking on a jQuery button but not straight away on page load?

Many thanks

Comment: This is ultra basic css...go through some tutorials

Comment: @AlivetoDie That would be true if there is blank space between those selectors. It's not about parent>child but a single element.

Comment: You're supposed to research before asking a question. See CSS Selectors at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors), [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) and [W3C](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/). Also, please read [ask]. Welcome to SO.

Comment: Thanks for saying that, however if you look through the CSS selectors list at both mozilla and w3schools which I had then you will see it is not listed there on both. And some basic CSS principle for one might not be so for another. 

Ref: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Selectors

Comment: Those are just references...there are lots of other resources on web to learn how css works

Comment: Re-reading your question (which I still find poorly researched) and the provided answers, I decided to add mine, which links to and comments the current official source. I believe that is what you asked for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#foo.bar` refers to the element with together `foo` id and `bar` class.

```js
$('#foo.bar').fadeOut('slow');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='foo' class='bar'>box</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

That means element with id `foo` and class `bar`, shortened to `#foo.bar`

Comment: Just what I was going to put.

Answer (score 1):

`[id][class]`
`#wrapper` is id of an element, and `.MenuDisplay` is class. Element must have that id and class to get that CSS work.

Answer (score 1):

`#foo.bar`

matches an element that has both id = "foo" and class = "bar".

Answer (score 1):

Well As far as I can understand from your question,
**jQuery Selectors allow you to select and manipulate HTML element(s)** or select HTML elements based on their name, id, classes, types, attributes, values of attributes and much more. **It's based on the existing CSS Selectors**, and in addition, it has some own custom selectors.

In this case:

`#foo.bar` points to an element in the DOM that has an **id="foo"** and a **class="bar"**.

**jQuery Selector Tester to demonstrate the different selectors:**

[jQuery Selectors Test Page](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/trysel.asp)

Hope I could help!

Comment: OP is showing a css rule. This answer goes off on a completely irrelevant tangent into using jQuery

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Excellent link too. The problem I was facing was that I didn't realise classToggle could work when a class wasn't already created, I presumed you could only toggle something which was existing in the first place but nah, jQuery can create a it before toggling on and off.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are asking what a ***sequence of selectors*** means.

According to current [W3C standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/#sequence), it is...

> ...a chain of [simple selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/#simple-selectors-dfn) that are not separated by a [combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/#combinators). It always begins with a type selector or a universal selector. No other type selector or universal selector is allowed in the sequence.

Not everyone considers the second sentence of the definition true, because, for example, `#this` or `.that` appear not to begin with either a type selector (`a`, `div`, `span`, etc...) or a universal selector (`*`). However, one should bear in mind that...

...whenever a sequence of selectors does not begin with a type or universal selector, it "defaults" to starting with an omissible [universal selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/#universal-selector).

So,  `#this` is a shorthand for `*#this`, `.that` is a shorthand for `*.that`. And `#this.that` is a shorthand for `*#this.that`.

In fact, if you read the entire universal selector paragraph, you'll notice a note at its end recommending it not to be omitted.

However, almost nobody respects this recommendation and, in practice, the only time you'll see a universal selector is when someone wants to give a `CSS` property to every single element in the page.
Like in `* {box-sizing: border-box;}`

As a side note, not omitting the universal selector in your CSS is supposed to make it faster. This is not difficult to test and appears to be true, but the differences are negligible.